# Android: XML from API to XML in MainActivity

Tags: java, android, xml

This Question may be hard to present, but I'll give it a go.

So I am attempting to create an application within Android Studio that determines what phase the moon is currently in. After some research, I didn't really find anything but then I found timeanddate.com offer Astronomy API packages.

I gave the trial a go, which came with the moon phases.

Now I used a Query Builder to essentially guide me through getting the Results in XML, and received the following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data version="2">
  <location id="750">
    <geo>
      <name>Lord Howe Island</name>
      <state>Lord Howe Island</state>
      <country id="au">Australia</country>
      <latitude>-31.557</latitude>
      <longitude>159.086</longitude>
    </geo>
    <astronomy>
      <object name="moon">
        <day date="2018-09-03" moonphase="thirdquarter">
          <event type="thirdquarter" isotime="2018-09-03T13:07+10:30" hour="13" min="7"/>
        </day>
      </object>
    </astronomy>
  </location>
</data>
```

So I have the data, now I am stuck at actually getting it on an Activity in Android Studio.

To the extent of my knowledge, XML in Android Studio does not look like the XML I received, with lines such as

```
 android:text="text"
```

Can someone point me in the right direction? I have no idea where to go from here, now that I have some information to work with. Clearly, this is not a matter of copy and paste the XML from time and date. I just don't know the next steps to show something like "**Lord Howe Island, Third Quarter Moon" (As seen in the XML supplied)**

Thanks, everyone, even the tiniest of help is useful.

Comment: Parse the result you got and move the values you want to show on the UI to your UI views.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to issue the API request in the background, parse the result and update the UI.

This has anything you will need: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml

Feel free to ask for more info!